# IF NOT EXISTS in mysql showing syntax error

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I am trying to convert this tsql to mysql but showing error need help

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE FormAdd 

  @formName varchar(MAX)   
  AS  
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_Form WHERE formName=@formName)  
  BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO tbl_Form  
  (formName)  
  VALUES  
  (@formName)  
  SELECT @@identity  
  END  
  ELSE  
  BEGIN  
  SELECT  '-1'  
  END
```

mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FormAdd              
  (p_formName varchar(500)   )
  begin

  INSERT INTO tbl_Form (formName)  
  VALUES (p_formName)
   where NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tbl_Form WHERE formName=p_formName)  ;

  SELECT Last_insert_id() as returnvalue ;

  SELECT  '-1'  ;
end
```

Comment: What is exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: `INSERT INTO` logically has no `WHERE` clause. Is that where your error is?

Comment: Is it correct that the goal of this is to insert a new row in `tbl_form` if `p_formname` does not already exist?

Comment: yeah @MichaelBerkowski ...........................

Comment: up above is mssql.. i am trying to convert it to mysql below of it

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was syntactically invalid because logically, an `INSERT` statement cannot contain a `WHERE` clause since it does not act on existing rows.

If the purpose is to insert only if the value for `p_formname` is not already present, then an appropriate step would be to define a unique index on that column first.  Then, construct your procedure to attempt the insert and inspect [the `ROW_COUNT()` value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) to see if one was inserted and act accordingly, returning `-1` if not to adapt your existing T-SQL procedure.

First create the unique index on `p_formname`:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Form ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_formName` (`formName`);
```

Then your procedure should use [`INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to attempt to insert the row. Per the documentation, the value of `ROW_COUNT()` will be `0` if a new row was not inserted or `1` if it was.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FormAdd (p_formName varchar(500))
BEGIN
  /* Attempt the insert, overwrite with the same value if necessary */
  INSERT INTO tbl_Form (formName) VALUES (p_formName) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE formName = p_formName;

  /* Return the LAST_INSERT_ID() for a new row and -1 otherwise */
  SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN ROW_COUNT() = 1 THEN LAST_INSERT_ID() 
      ELSE -1
    END AS returnValue;
END
```